# Debug in VS 2017 when running through task configuration

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, makefile, visual-studio-2017

I have this simple program called **main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  puts("hi");
  puts("bye");
  return 0;
}
```

and this **makefile**:

```
run: main.o
    gcc main.o -o run

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c -g $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f run main.o
```

Now I want to use it in VS 2017. So I opened the program folder in VS (main.c and the makefile are located there). Then I configured these tasks for it:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "BUILD",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "workingDirectory": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "command": "make",
      "type": "default"
    },
    {
      "taskName": "RUN",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "workingDirectory": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "command": "run",
      "type": "default"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I tried to do next, is to put break point in the main function and then use the RUN task. I thought VS will stop the running on the break point but that didn't happen and the program run till the end of it.

How can I use the task configuration, so that when I click on RUN - it will stop on the break points that I put?
It's important for me to emphasize that I want to debug the program using the task configuration only and not via other ways that VS have.

Comment: Not a C question (in the SO context). Tag removed.

Comment: @pmg, The issue is about C development and therefore I put the C tag. Anyway, no problem it was removed

Comment: I still think your question is not a "general question concerning the C language", but re-added the tag to increase visibility.